# .Net Maui How to Add User Input to List

Tags: maui

In .Net Maiu, I have a userInput field and Add button.

I enter a value into the userInput field and click the add button.

I want to see my input added to the list on the same page.

I have the following code:

MainPage.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout 
            Margin="20"
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Entry x:Name="entry"   
               MaxLength="255"
               MinimumWidthRequest="500"   
               Placeholder="Name"
               FontSize="18"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            
            <Button
                x:Name="AddToList"
                Text="Add"
                Clicked="AddInputItemTolist"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyName}" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MauiApp1
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddInputItemToList(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

    }

    public class MyName
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
       
    }
}
```

Could you please advise how to do this.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your Model: MyName being added to the `ListView`, the `ItemsSource` should be `ObservableCollection`.

Here's the code snippet below for your reference:

XAML:

```
  <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout 
            Margin="20"
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Entry x:Name="entry"   
               MaxLength="255"
               MinimumWidthRequest="500"   
               Placeholder="Name"
               FontSize="18"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                x:Name="AddToList"
                Text="Add"
                Clicked="AddInputItemTolist"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyNames}" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public ObservableCollection<MyName> MyNames { get;set;} = new ObservableCollection<MyName>();
      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

          BindingContext = this;
      }

    private void AddInputItemTolist(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        var myName = new MyName { 
            Name = entry.Text
            };
        
        MyNames.Add(myName);
    }

    public class MyName
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things at first glance:

- You're binding your class `MyName` as the `ItemsSource` in your
  `<ListView>` - this isn't going to work; `ItemsSource` expects the name of
  a *property* of your `MainPage` class, which must be (I believe) an `IList`, and that wouldn't be a logical interface for a datum like a name in the
  first place.
- You'll want to define a collection property for your `MainPage` class,
  probably something like `public List<MyName> Names { get; set; }`, and use that property name in the `ItemsSource`.
- Define content for your `<ListView>` - `<ListView.View>`, `<ListView.ItemTemplate>`, etc.
- Literally just access a property called `AddToList` in your click handler - `x:Name="[thing]"` makes an element accessible to your page via a property named [thing].

If any of this is unclear, your favorite search engine will take you the rest of the way.